# Start process in background at keybind (append `& disown` on Ctrl+Enter)

Tags: command-line, bash

Let's say I want to open Chrome, Sublime Idea, etc. from the command line while maintaining the control of the terminal.

Is there a way to append `& disown` to the command in Bash when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> or other convenient combination?

I tried to make alias for them, e.g. `alias subl='subl & disown'`, but passing arguments won't work anymore and having to write aliases for all the programs I want to use this way is too much of a hassle. There has to be a smarter way.

Comment: Look at shell functions.

Comment: I added ` "\C-e": ' & disown\n' ` in .inputrc and it does what I want on ctrl+e. For some reason it doesn't work with \n instead of e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment:

> I added `"\C-e": ' & disown\n'` in `.inputrc` and it does what I want on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>. For some reason it doesn't work with `\n` instead of `e`.

I don't think `\n` is the right string to use, but there's a bigger problem: in a console <kbd>Enter</kbd> itself is `\C-M` i.e. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>, so <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> is just <kbd>Enter</kbd> and you cannot tell them apart.

You can, however, tell apart <kbd>Enter</kbd> and <kbd>Meta (aka Alt)</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. Place this line into your `.inputrc`:

```
"\C-\M-M":' & disown\n'
```

and hit <kbd>Meta (aka Alt)</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> whenever you want to use it.

Comment: I also tried with shift+enter "\C-J":' & disown\n' , but the \n at the end got me in a loop. I've replaced the \n with \r and now it works fine. Thanks for your answer, I'll find something useful to map it to the alt key too. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I've learned that **\r** shares the same ASCII code as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>, which means <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> is equivalent to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>. Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> twice doesn't make any sense, so <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> can't be used together in terminal without some xterm [translation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38917588/how-to-bind-ctrlenter-when-using-readline-library).

I managed to do the trick with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> by adding `"\C-E": ' & disown\n '` in `.inputrc`.